# lifecycleScope aware fragment scope coroutine calls viewmodel coroutine scope function even though not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I have a `lifecycle` aware fragment scope coroutine function that checks whether a value received from the fragments' parent activity has a certain value.  If the value is `null` a function is called that has `viewModelScope.launch` coroutine scope to start a count down before showing a dialog to inform the user that the value disables certain app functionalities.
The problem is that the `viewModelScope.launch` coroutine function is called all the time even though the conditional if statement is not true.
My question is why would a `viewModelScope` coroutine function be called if it is inside a conditional that is clearly false?  I did notice that if I `Log` an output inside the `if` conditional it is not logged and if I `Log` output outside the `viewModelScope.launch` coroutine it is also not called.  So the scoped code runs notwithstanding the value of the conditional.
The workaround for this was to make the viewmodel function a `suspend` function and remove the `viewModelScope.launch` coroutine.  But why would a function be called that does not meet a conditional.  Does coroutines transcend the boundaries of logic?
The `lifecycleScope` function has the following make up:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        viewModel.status.collectLatest {
            
            binding.contentScanner.tvScannerStatus.text = it
            if (statusCheck(it) == null) {
                viewModel.reactToInactiveScanner(it)  // This function is called even though the condition is false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `viewModelScope` coroutine:

```
fun reactToInactiveScanner(s: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        for(i in 1..5) {
            if(isScannerUnavailable(s)) break
            delay(1000L)
        }
        _scannerActive.value = isScannerUnavailable(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: removing the other code, you're basically saying an if statement isn't working as expected?  Either its your code or if statements are broken, my gut tells me its the former, unfortuntately the vital function code for `statusCheck` isn't included, either way `statusCheck(it) == null` is equating to `true` and then launching a coroutine that lasts either 5+ seconds or for the scope of the viewmodel.

Comment: @Mark The viemodel `reactToInactiveScanner` method that is inside the conditional evaluating `statusCheck(it) == null` is executing even though it is `false`.  As stated if I put a `Log` inside the `if` statement it does not get executed.  Also if I put a `Log` outside the `viewModelScope.launch` coroutine that is inside the `reactToInactiveScanner` method it is also not executed.  But everything inside the coroutine does get executed, but it only lasts 5 seconds if `isScannerUnavailable` evaluates to false.  Why is the code executed inside the if conditional if it evaluates to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `statusCheck(it)` is null when you think it is not ooor, since  `reactToInactiveScanner(s: String)` is launching a coroutine in the view model scope and suspending for at least 5 seconds, and given that the viewmodel survives configuration change, doesnt matter what the lifecycle is doing, the coroutine in the viewmodel scope will keep running for 5 seconds.

try to make the function suspending :

```
suspend fun reactToInactiveScanner(s: String) {
        for(i in 1..5) {
            if(isScannerUnavailable(s)) break
            delay(1000L)
        }
        _scannerActive.value = isScannerUnavailable(s)
}
```

and launch it in the lifecycle scope, so when the lifecycle stop the coroutine get canncelled and when it starts the coroutine gets launched again

Comment: This does not answer my question.  And you posted the solution I gave in my question.  The question is about lifecycle aware function that ignores a conditional.

Comment: @Hmerman6006 so might be the second reason, the function is called when the condition is true and keeps running in the ViewmodelScope wich is different then the LifecycleScope

Comment: As stated in my question the conditional is false.

Comment: so why did you put the conditional if it is always false? is there a case where it is true?@Hmerman6006

Comment: Where did I say it is always false.  It is false if the status of the scanner is known and true otherwise.  I get what you are saying, so let me run the test again, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @Hmerman6006 so when it is true it lunches a coroutine in the ViewModelScope wich keeps running even if the lifecycle pauses or some cases even if it stops (for example when your viewmodel is bounded to the activity lifecycle)

Comment: I am sorry form my quick judgement.  You are correct in your second analysis.  I used the `MutableStateFlow`  variable to check for changes inside the scoped function and it showed that the initial scanner value changed on 3 seconds but was unknown before that due the function scope argument.  If you amend your answer I can upvote it.